# How to use Spring AOP to advise a bean of class X with certain id instead of all beans of class X

Tags: java, spring, aop

In spring aop you can create advices that will effect all instance of a certain type but what I want is to advise a bean declaration not all beans of that type.

```
<bean id="bean1" class="type1"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="type1"/>
```

I want to advise `bean1` not all beans of `type1`. What is the best approach?

Comment: the other bean id should be bean2

Comment: or rather, anything that is not 'bean1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Spring Documentation regarding AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html):

> Spring AOP also supports an additional PCD (PointCut Designator) named
>   'bean'. This PCD allows you to limit the matching of join points to a
>   particular named Spring bean, or to a set of named Spring beans (when
>   using wildcards). The 'bean' PCD has the following form:
>
> ***bean(idOrNameOfBean)***
>
> The 'idOrNameOfBean' token can be the name of any Spring bean: limited
>   wildcard support using the '*' character is provided, so if you
>   establish some naming conventions for your Spring beans you can quite
>   easily write a 'bean' PCD expression to pick them out. As is the case
>   with other pointcut designators, the 'bean' PCD can be &&'ed, ||'ed,
>   and ! (negated) too.